# Fractional Composite of Functions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, tetration

I would like to know how I can calculate a fractional composition of a function. Let be $f(x)$, where $x \in R$ and $f(x) \in R$. I now how to do $f(f(x))=f^2(x)$. Now suppose I would like to do $f^{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$. Any tip? In other words, $f^n(x)$ is a $n$ composition of a function. Usually, $n \in N$. Supose now I would like to calculate a result for $n=1.2$.

Comment: One can look at a collection of Q&A in mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/fractional-iteration or here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetration

Answer (score 4):

I put a number of relevant articles at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html  I tell people to start with the obituary of Baker.

The short version is this:

- if your function has **no fixpoints**, you can mostly manage this by Kneser's method.
- If there is just **one fixpoint**,

  - and the modulus of the derivative there is not $1,$ fairly easy by Schroder's equation.
  - However, if the derivative there is $1,$ it is a big song and dance invented by Ecalle in the 1970's. I have only second-hand accounts, but enough to apply, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence including my own answer.

Comment: It applies for $n \in R$?

Comment: Only under the most fortunate circumstances does it apply for all real $n.$ More common is that it applies for rational $n$ with a certain denominator. This is a result of Baker, finished by his student Liverpool.

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[Functional square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) are relatively easy to find through [Functional Conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Conjugacy) specifications of generic iterated functions; find the general iterate, and  set *n*=1/2 in the general expression, such as the ones available and listed there.

For example, the functional square root of the *n*th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) $T_n$ is evidently $\cos (\sqrt{n} \arccos (x)) $ --- which, however, is *not* a polynomial, in general.

As Will Jagy already mentioned, in general, around a fixed point, say $f(0)=0$, the standard tried-and-true method is [Schröder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation), $\psi(f(x))=f'(0) ~\psi(x)$, a triumph of functional conjugacy, provided *f '* there ≠1. Having found *ψ*, one has  $f^{1/2}(x)=\psi^{-1}\left (\sqrt{f'(0)} ~ \psi(x)\right )$.

If it *is* =1, at the fixed point, however, all is not lost, and conjugacy still delivers: [Curtright,  Jin, & Zachos, *JouPhys* **A** Math-Th 44.40 (2011): 405205](https://www.academia.edu/6688043/Approximate_solutions_of_functional_equations) illustrates how $f^n \circ g \circ f^{-n}$ will improve an initial approximant *g* rapidly and dramatically for large *n*.

(This is illustrated there for intuitive functions such as $f=\sin x$, blue, around the origin, where the half iterate is orange, the second iterate is red, and so on...)
[image: iterates of sine function]

Answer (score 1):

Just some simple examples, allowing much obvious/natural versions of a fractional iterate:

- Let $f(x)=x+a$ then $f(f(x))=x+2a$ , $f(f(f(x))) = x+3a$ and in general $f°^h(x)=x+h\cdot a$. Then $f°^{0.5} (x) = x+0.5 a$
- Let $f(x)=x \cdot a$ then $f(f(x))=x \cdot a^2$ , $f(f(f(x))) = x \cdot a^3$ and in general $f°^h(x)=x  \cdot a^h $ . Then  $f°^{0.5} (x) = x \cdot a^{0.5} $
- Let $f(x)=x ^ a$ then $f(f(x))=x ^{ a^2}$ , $f(f(f(x))) = x ^ { a^3}$ and in general $f°^h(x)=x  ^{ a^h} $ . Then  $f°^{0.5} (x) = x ^ {\sqrt {a}} $

If a function has a power series without constant term , then you can find a formal power series for a fractional iterate. If $f(x) = ax + O(x^2)$ and $0<a<1$ then sometimes that series for fractional iterates might have a nonzero radius of convergence. If the power series *has* a constant term, one can sometimes use *conjugacy* to find a formal power series. More on this using the method of Carleman-matrices, see wikipedia:Carleman-matrix. For the specific case of $f(x) = a^x$ see wikipedia:tetration also there is something in wikipedia:hyperoperations .
Also note that a collection of Q&A about this subject is in MSE (tag::tetration, tag::hyperoperation) and in MO tag::fractional-iteration.

A very involved discussion can be found at tetration-forum: http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum and many more links can be found using google-search. In mathoverflow you can find this question with answers: [MO1](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231934/7710) , [MO2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66538/7710) , [MO3](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264023/7710)

---

The problem is really not simple, the beginning of its consideration in a systematic way was only in the 19th century with N. Abel and E. Schroeder providing fairly general schemes - but only for functions of certain classes. Some singular gems might have been found earlier, say Euler's/Goldbach's finding of the range for the base $a$ in $f(x)=a^x$ where this converges even if infinitely iterated (but no *fractional* iterate has been discussed with this)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function g(x) with

g(g(x)) = f(x) , then you could formally set

g(x) = $f^{1/2}(x)$

Comment: But it will be difficult to find such a g(x) for a given f(x).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think it is not the case. When I indicate $1/2$ I would like to mean that I am doing a partial composition. Suppose $n$ is the number of times of composition. Usually $n \in N$. I would like to calculate when $n=1.2$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

The fractional iterate is NON unique even with well behaved function : check the very nice book : Z.A Melzak : "Companion to concrete mathematics"  Vol 1 : page 56  to 62