# half composite function

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

There is half derivative. Is there any definition of half composite function? Or is it possible to define half composite of a function?

1) $f^n=f \circ \cdots \circ f $ ($n$-times, $n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$)

2) if $f$ has an inverse the we can define $f^{-n}$.

3) Can we define $f^{1/2}$ or $f^{\pi}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676229/fractional-composite-of-functions

Comment: You are right. Since it has an answer now. I cant delete it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be defined, but may or may not exist for a given function $f$.

For example, see [half iterate of $x^2+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208996/half-iterate-of-x2c)

In MO, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/fractional-iteration

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't seen the other related question. I thinkI have to close this one.