# Is There a Concept of Fractional Composition?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, analysis, category-theory

Does there exist a concept of fractional composition for functions? Continuous or differentiable functions?

Comment: Yes, in my remembering, you have some notion of square root, cubique root and so on. Something like $g= f^{[1/2]}$ if $g\circ g =f$. This is particularly easy to extend for diagonalisable linear functions.

Comment: Related: [Fractional Composite of Functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676229/fractional-composite-of-functions)

Comment: ^Linear in the sense of an operator, or in the sense of a line? Are there special circumstances whence we have a single g (within our category)?

Comment: I mean if $f(x)=Dx$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is some diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries, then $f^{[r]}(x):=\operatorname{diag}(d_1^{r},\ldots,d_n^{r})$. Such trick can be generalized relatively easily to positive semidefinite matrices. (I know more or less nothing about category theory)

Comment: Well, if you look for something like $f^{[r]}$ for rational (or real) $r$ and $f$ a morphism of a category, you preferably want $f$ to be an *endomorphism*, and thus suddenly we are talking about $r$th power in a monoid.

Comment: Wha'ts a fractional composition in your mind ? Standard composition states $(g\circ f)(x):=g(f(x))$. But I can't even imagine what "integer composition" would mean: for example, $(g\circ^2 f)(x):= ?$".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I understood it as compositions of endomorphisms as suggested by Berci. For positive integers: $f\colon A \to A$, $f^{0}(x)=x$, and $f^{k}(x)=f\big(f^{k-1}(x)\big)$ for $k\in \Bbb N$. Based on that, are there generalizations of this idea to define e.g. $f^{3/4}$?
(I should have added that in the Bounty notice....).

Comment: @JacobWakem May I edit your question to push it in the same direction as proposed in my previous comment?

Comment: @ago: as it is a self-composition, it is better called *fractional iteration* I guess. Wikipedia will tell you more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows.2C_and_negative_iterates.

Comment: Search "fractional iteration" here, 27 matches.  You can also try "half iteration" and "continuous iteration".

Comment: Duplicate of [676229](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676229/fractional-composite-of-functions).  See [WP}(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, fractional function iteration is defined.

Like it works for natural iteration

$$f^{(n)}(x):=f(f(\cdots f(x)\cdots)),$$

and (negative) integer iteration

$$f^{-n}(x):=(f^{-1})^{(n)}(x)$$

you can generalize to rationals with the functional equation

$$g(x):=f^{(n/m)}(x)\iff g^{(m)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x).$$

For example, the iterative square root is defined as

$$g(x):=f^{1/2}(x)\iff g(g(x))=f(x).$$

In the case of the identity function, you get the so-called Babbage equation,

$$g(g(x))=x.$$

A particular solution is $g(x)=-x$, and as you can check, more solutions are found as

$$g(x)=h^{-1}(-h(x))$$ where $h$ is an arbitrary invertible function.

For instance, with $h(x)=\ln(x+1)$,

$$g(x)=\exp(-\ln(x+1))-1=-\frac x{x+1}.$$

So this square root isn't unique.

---

If $f(x)=x^r$ is a power law, the $n^{th}$ iterate is $((x^r)^{r\cdots})^r=x^{r^n}$ so that a particular solution of

$$g^{(m)}(x)=(x^r)^{(n)}$$ is another power law

$$g(x)=x^s$$ with $s^m=r^n$, or $s=r^{n/m}$.

$$(x^r)^{(q)}=x^{r^q}.$$

---

As another example, the iteration of a linear law gives

$$(ax+b)^{(n)}=a(\cdots a(ax+b)+b\cdots)+b=a^nx+\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b,$$ so that a fractional iterate can also be linear

$$(ax+b)^{(n/m)}=g(x)=Ax+B$$ with

$$A^m=a^n,\frac{A^m-1}{A-1}B=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b$$

or

$$A=a^{n/m},B=b\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}\frac{A-1}{A^m-1}=\frac{a^{n/m}-1}{a-1}.$$

$$(ax+b)^{(q)}=a^qx+\frac{a^q-1}{a-1}b.$$

Comment: It's a bit abusive to say that "fractional function iteration is defined". What is defined is what it means for a function $g$ to be a fractional iterate of a function $f$. Otherwise it's like saying "the complex square root is defined". It makes sense to say that $i$ is a square root of $-1$, it doesn't make sense to talk about "the square root of $-1$". Similarly, when you write $g(x) := f^{(n/m)}(x)$ as if it were a definition of $g$, that's abusive IMO.

Comment: Your iteration is not uni uely defined! I guess if we had a metric space or a particular continuous process that the function performs to get from x to f(x) it might be uni uely defined.

Comment: @JacobWakem: it is not "my iteration", and this definition looks quite natural. It ends-up in multiple solutions. Remember that $z^n=w$ doesn't define a unique $n^{th}$ root either.